# Как в Yii2 добавить произвольную версию в путь к файлам JS и CSS?

Tags: yii2, yii

В проект на Yii2 нужно интегрировать в URL загрузки CSS и JS псевдо-версию. В примере ниже v-1.2 это автоматически подставленное произвольное значение.

```
<script src="/js/lib/v-1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Это нужно, что бы обеспечить обход кэширования на клиентской стороне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С версии 2.0.3:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

[Источник](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#cache-busting)